# Values of components in ACPL 337J

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver

[I was going through datasheet of mosfet gate driver.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-4390EN_DS_ACPL-337J_2014-05-09-909393.pdf) I wonder why is the value of component the specified one only. On page no. 13 fig 23, why the value of resistor between pin 3 and pin 6 is 10k ohm only and not any other value? Similarly, capacitors between pin 6 and 8 are of value 330pF. Why not any other value?[image: Recommended application circuit]
The attached diagram is of recommended application circuit provided by Avago Technologies. Also if I am to use it in LTspice with a [mosfet](https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/SCT2080KEHR/sct2080kehr-e), what are the additional components and connection that are to be made so that the driver can driver the mosfet? The mosfet is to be operated at a frequency of 100kHZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10k resistors are pulling up UVLO (pin 5) and Fault (pin 6). 10k is a pretty standard part used for this.

The 10k uses the available output current from those pins (for a 0.4V output) of between 4mA and 9mA to ensure they actually do go to a valid low when driven that way. Larger resistors (but not smaller as the outputs cannot sink enough current for smaller resistors) could be used. The ones here are suggested and are typical values that are easy to get.

The capacitors are filters from those pins to ground to filter glitches on the outputs.

The time constant is (ignoring where they might be connected elsewhere) 3.3uSec so this would filter out sub microsecond glitches due to false internal triggers (the device is expected to be used in rather noisy environments such as motor drives).

Larger filter capacitors could be used for more immunity at the expense of response time. Smaller devices may let false triggers through.